# Compute inside SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

is it possible to compute (+, -, *, /) inside SwiftUI like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var input: Double = 1000
    @State var input2: Double = 1000
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ExtractedView(value: ($input * $input2))
            }
        
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
struct ExtractedView: View {
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ...
            Spacer()
            TextField("Value", text: $value)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

I can also ask like this:

I have 2 TextFields, I want to have the following: If I enter one value in the first box, the second box should show the value * 2

Comment: Yes. Is there more to your question? You shouldn't include `$` here, however. That passes a binding, and you can't do math on a binding itself, just its value.

Comment: Then I get "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Binding<Double>'" but I need to keep them as a State since I change them inside a TextField

Comment: Would you show code of ExtractedView?

Comment: If you change the bound value inside a TextField, what do you expect to happen to `input` and `input2`? Bindings are two-way.

Comment: Added ExtractedView

Comment: Thanks for the updated code; this definitely gets to the heart of my question: What do you want to happen to `input` and `input2` when the user modifies the text field? Where do you expect to store the user's input? (I'm ignoring the fact that Double is not a String and so can't be bound to a text field anyway; I assume that's just an artifact of simplifying the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be a one-way binding (so that changes in the text field will not modify `input` and `input2`), then you can pass it as a constant binding:

```
ExtractedView(value: .constant(input * input2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following function inside the `struct` you can compute your variables and pass it as `Binding`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var input: Double = 1000
    @State var input2: Double = 1000
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ExtractedView(value: computeBinding())
        }
    }
    
    private func computeBinding() -> Binding<Double> {
        return Binding<Double>(get: { () -> Double in
            self.input * self.input2 //** compute (+, -, *, /)
        }) { (Double) in
        }
    }
}

struct ExtractedView: View {
    @Binding var value: Double
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: In the edit part you have added, the ``value`` should be `Binding<String>` to use it in the `TextField`. or `TextField("Value", text: .constant("\(value)"))`